# How do I create two simple relations in Prolog?

Tags: list, prolog

Trying to create two Prolog relations by defining them as `affix` and `suffix` in order to further define them on the given lists, like so

```
?- consult(relpro).
% relpro compiled 0.00 sec, 956 bytes
true.

?- affix([a,b,c],[a,b,c,e,f]).
true.

?- affix([a,b,c], [a,b,e,f]).
false.

?- suffix([e,f],[a,b,e,f]).
true.

?- suffix([a,b,c],[a,b,c,e,f]).
false.
```

Looking for suggestions to get started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use the widely available predicate [`append/3`](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/prologue#append)!

```
affix_of([E|Es], [E|Es]).                           % [E|Es] is affix  of [E|Es]
affix_of([X|Xs], Es) :- append([_|_], [X|Xs], Es).  % [X|Xs] is suffix of Es
affix_of([],     _).                                % []     is affix  of anything
affix_of([X|Xs], Es) :- append([X|Xs], [_|_], Es).  % [X|Xs] is prefix of Es
```

Some sample queries using SICStus Prolog 4.3.2:

```
| ?- affix_of([a,b,c], [a,b,c,e,f]).  % Is [a,b,c] an affix of [a,b,c,d,e]?
yes                                   % Yes! It is a prefix.

| ?- affix_of([a,b,c], [a,b,e,f]).    % Is [a,b,c] an affix of [a,b,e,f]?
no                                    % No! Neither prefix nor suffix.

| ?- affix_of(Affix, [a,b,c,d]).      % What are the affixes of [a,b,c,d]?
Affix = [a,b,c,d] ? ;
Affix = [b,c,d] ? ;
Affix = [c,d] ? ;
Affix = [d] ? ;
Affix = [] ? ;
Affix = [a] ? ;
Affix = [a,b] ? ;
Affix = [a,b,c] ? ;
no
```

Comment: @Aspersum. At first I did not get that... It's better to name that `suffix_of/2`, not `affix_of/2`. It could be defined as `suffix_of(Xs,Es) :- append(_,Xs,Es).`.

Comment: @Aspersum. Do you want to see an older version of my answer for `affix_of/2`? Go to http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36354206/revisions ...

Comment: @Aspersum. I see. `prefix_of(Prefix,List) :- append(Prefix,_,List).` and `suffix_of(Suffix,List) :- append(_,Suffix,List).` should suit you right... Sample queries and answers: `?- prefix_of(Xs,[a,b,c,d]).` gives `Xs = [] ; 
Xs = [a] ; Xs = [a, b] ; Xs = [a, b, c] ; Xs = [a, b, c, d] ; false.` and `?- suffix_of(Xs,[a,b,c,d]).` gives `Xs = [a, b, c, d] ; Xs = [b, c, d] ; Xs = [c, d] ; Xs = [d] ; Xs = [] ; false.`

Comment: Ok, now I got it. My previous comment should fit well.. And by the way,  you are using the name "affix" the wrong way, you mean to say "prefix".

Comment: @Aspersum. I was a bit confused by your improper use of the word "affix". All prefixes are affixes, but not vice versa...

Comment: @Aspersum. Calling a list suffix "suffix" is actually *a lot better* than calling a list suffix "postfix". **(1)** Don't use the name "postfix" in this particular context! Keep it reserved for characterizing binary operators that are used for writing arithmetic expressions.

Comment: @Aspersum. **(2)** Here comes the good stuff! Develop a habit of trying to find good (descriptive, self-explanatory and concise) names for constants and relations. `suffix/2` is okay, *but* (without looking at the actual code) can you guess which argument is the prefix is (and which one the original list is)? I can't. In fact one of the problems you had was a direct consequence of this. So: make it clear! THIS is why I insisted on using the name `suffix_of` instead of `suffix`: it implies that the 1st argument is the suffix and that the 2nd is the "bigger" list that the 1st is a suffix of.

Comment: @Aspersum. Concluding, I suggest you use exactly the following names for these relations: `prefix_of/2` and `suffix_of/2`. And use 'em like this; the following goals should prove correct: **(1)** `prefix_of([a,b],[a,b,c,d,e])` **(2)** `suffix_of([d,e],[a,b,c,d,e])`.

Comment: @Aspersum. Oh, one more thing... if you want to flip the argument order, make sure you adapt the relation names accordingly. Again, the following goals should hold true: **(1)** `list_prefix([a,b,c,d,e],[a,b])` **(2)** `list_suffix([a,b,c,d,e],[d,e])` ... Get the picture? HTH

Comment: @Aspersum. **нет!** First, names **are** just to important to be left aside. Second, using predicate names `prefix` can easily **clash** with existing built-in and library predicates. For instance, with SWI-Prolog `lists:prefix/2` is library predicate which is auto-loaded by default upon first use. Third, be careful and use the right terminology: Some affixes are prefixes, but **not every affix is a prefix!** Fourth, **I stand corrected regarding "postfix vs suffix"**: TIL both can be used. Fifth, it seems to me you are almost done!

Comment: @Aspersum. In short: I made five claims. Which one(s) didn't reach you?

Comment: Second. The terminology has been chosen by Prof. and the task is to do it accordingly on which I'm struggling from the past week. We've to solve it with the definition postfix as the second rule.

Answer (score 2):

Grammars ([dcg](/questions/tagged/dcg)) are very apt to define such relations:

```
... -->
   [] | [_], ... .

seq([]) --> [].
seq([E|Es]) --> [E], seq(Es).

affix(Xs, Zs) :-
   phrase( ( seq(Xs), ... ), Zs).

suffix(Xs, Zs) :-
   phrase( ( ..., seq(Xs) ), Zs).
```

In this manner, the symmetry becomes much more visible. If you are unsure about the formalism just read this [primer](http://www.metalevel.at/prolog/dcg.html).

Further these definition are only true for lists. Other definitions hold also for some "accidental" non-lists, like:  `suffix(non_list, Zs).`